# Find out the memory a process is using

Tags: powershell, memory

I have a few servers that I currently have to remote onto each one and check the same component to see how much memory it is using so I can audit it on a daily basis.  I was wondering if there was a way to write a script to do this?  Maybe a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 6):

There's a couple of ways using Get-Process. You can invoke the Get-Process to find out different memory usage of processes.

If you have powershell remoting you can invoke this command through the session using Invoke-Command -Session $Session.

Not sure which one of the memory sets you would want to report on, but you can select the different memory sets of your process.

Example:

```
Get-Process|select ProcessName, Path, VirtualMemorySize, PrivateMemorySize, NonpagedSystemMemorySize, PagedMemorySize, PeakPagedMemorySize
```

If you know the name of your process you can do the following

```
$process = Get-Process -Name "MyProcess.exe" 
# Access its properties or report based on its properties
$process.VirtualMemorySize
```

If you want the script for all servers from one host/machine you could do like following:

```
# Array of PSSessions or you could use $computerNames with Invoke-command -ComputerName $computerNames instead
$session = @(); 
$results = Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock {
   return Get-Process -Name "MyProcess"|Select Name, Path, VirtualMemorySize
}
$results|ForEach-Object {    
   # Do something with each and every server result
}
```

Alternatively; you can use the Get-process directly with ComputerName if you have direct access to invoke the cmdlet remotely.

Example:

```
Get-Process -ComputerName $computerNames
```